# easy upgrade of all sp_blitz-procs?

Tags: sp-blitz

I wonder if you could make the upgrade of the procs easier and faster by providing a sqlcmd-skript or something which executes all sp_blitz[xxx].sql files.
I first did a little sqlcmd-script myself (but failed because of `quoted_identifiers`). It would be great if something like this could be a part of the package? Or is there already a easy way to implement new sp_blitz[xxx] versions on a server?

Comment: This isn't really a forum for requests for enhancement. If you'd like to suggest an enhancement, head on over to the Github repository at http://FirstResponderKit.org. However, be aware that you'll probably be asked to code it. :-D

Answer (score 3):

This is how I deploy them in my environment.

In SSMS, view Registered Servers, create a local server group called Staging and put all the Staging servers in there.
Right click on the Staging group and select New Query. This will open a new query window connected to all the servers in the group. Status bar will say Connected xx/yy where xx is the number of connected servers and yy is the total number of servers.

In the Query Window, paste the sp_Blitz code and execute it.

This applies the proc to all the Staging servers at once.

Repeat the process for the other sp_Blitz procs.

Repeat the process for the Production group of servers.

It only takes a few minutes to deploy all the sp_Blitz procs to a large number of servers this way.

Answer (score 0):

How you implement SP_BLITZ is up to you (so long as you abide by the T&Cs etc.)

If you are having specific problems with implementation then maybe refine your question a bit to ask that.

Otherwise I'll answer sort of answer one of your questions. If you want to help wit the development of Brent's SP_BLITZ etc. then check out the github site:
https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit

Comment: Yes I know It's up to me how I install the blitz-procs. Stil, It would be convenient to run all procs at once for a server. I take a look at github, thanks for the answer!